# Problemas ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "api/fichas",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( strData ){
        alert("work");
        $("#agenda .content").append(strData);
    }
}).done(function(){
    console.log("WORK");
});
```

Tengo este codigo en un boton, hace la peticion pero no muestra nada, Ni error ni que ya esta hecho (la funcion .done())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de `api/fichas` debería estar en formato JSON, si encuentra errores en el contenido y no es del tipo json, la función de respuesta `success`, `.done()` no serán llamadas, en cambio llamaría a **.fail()**

```
//codigo
}).fail(function(response, error){
  console.log(error); //si retorna 'parseerror', api/fichas no está devolviendo un formato JSON correcto
})
```

Comment: en el codigo de 'api/fichas' tenia header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: lo cambie a header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); y funciono